# How to invoke a user defined function using R Type Provider

Tags: r, f#, type-providers

I have a bunch of existing user defined functions that are already written in R and I would like to access them with the R type provider.  Normally, one would call source to bring the functions into the R environment.

Is it possible to do the same or similar with the current [R Type Provider](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 'R Type Provider' an f# thing?  I'm an R user but don't really know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Dason added hyper link.

Comment: From the description it looks like it just does R packages.  It's not too bad to put your functions into a package though which would expose them via the R Type Provider it seems.